# VBScript macro in QlikView: PasteSpecial method randomly fails

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, qlikview

I'm using a QlikView macro written in VBScript to export some pivot tables' data into some Excel templates. However it seems the PasteSpecial method that I use, fails from time to time.
Now, my question is, is there anything wrong with my code or should I handle the case the method fails during runtime? 
QlikView Macro code posted below:

```
    sub ExcelTable1TemplateUse  
    set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")  
    XLApp.Visible = True  
    set XLDoc = XLApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\BSS\Documents\Alfaintes\20171204 - Report prioritari\Reports\Tabel 1\Table1_Template_SingleUser.xlsx")  
    XLDoc.Sheets(1).Select  
    XLDoc.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Select  
    ActiveDocument.GetSheetObject("CH128").CopyTableToClipboard true
    XLDoc.Sheets(1).PasteSpecial -4163  
    end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when it fails?

And I think you can just

```
ActiveDocument.GetSheetObject("CH128").CopyTableToClipboard true
XLDoc.Sheets(1).Range.Cells("A1").PasteSpecial -4163
```

Comment: It breaks the execution when the paste fails.

Comment: As for the XLDoc.Sheets(1).Range.Cells.("A1").PasteSpecial - 4163, I get a "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: 'XLDoc.Sheets(...).Range' " error during runtime

Comment: Sorry, I didn' test it.

This works:
XLDoc.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial -4142

I don't know -4163 and it's also not working for me.

What are you trying to do? Transposing?